# Sharepoint Taxonomy 2019, C#, CSOM

Tags: taxonomy

example:

### I have terms like

```
 Sport
    Soccer
       Team 1
         player1
         player2
         player3
       Team 2
         player 1
         player 2
         player 3

       Team n     
         player n
         player n
         player n
```

### I need help to put the value of only the third level term, i.e (team 1 & team 2 upto Team n,) following the above format to be stored in an array using c# CSOM

output should be an array with only team1, team2 upto team n.

Note output should be an array.
example: a[] = {team1, team2, team3. .... team n} using c#, csom

Comment: What code have you tried, and what specific problems have you run into?

Comment: StackExchange is not a code writing service.  Share the code you have attempted and we will help you troubleshoot and make corrections.